# MySQL Auto increment primary key increases by 10

Tags: mysql, azure

On azure I created a new MySQL Database instance. In this db I create a table using this script:

```
CREATE TABLE ROLES(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ROLE_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Then I insert values using this script:

```
INSERT INTO `beezzy`.`roles` (`ROLE_NAME`) VALUES ('admin');
INSERT INTO `beezzy`.`roles` (`ROLE_NAME`) VALUES ('owner');
INSERT INTO `beezzy`.`roles` (`ROLE_NAME`) VALUES ('consultant');
```

after execution table contains such rows:

[image]

Why DB generates IDs like '11' and '21'?
I run the same script on my local machine and everything works fine. IDs was '1', '2', '3'

Comment: Please look at the **EDIT** and **MORE** sections of my answer. @OlehKurpiak

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please run the following query.

`SELECT @@auto_increment_increment`

If the value is more than 1 then set it to `1` by the following query:

`SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;`

**Note:** This change is visible for the current connection only.

**EDIT:**

In order to set it globally so that other connections can also see the change you need to set it for global and session too.

```
SET @@GLOBAL.auto_increment_increment = 1;

SET @@SESSION.auto_increment_increment = 1;
```

So other connections can see this change now.

**More:**

This value will be reset if you restart your `MySQL` server. In order to make this change permanent you need to write this variable under `[mysqld]` secion in your `my.cnf [for linux]` or `my.ini [for windows]` file.

```
[mysqld]
auto-increment-increment = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This help me :)

Comment: You are welcome. But you also should go through the [**clear db faqs**](https://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16). Peter already pointed out the reason. @OlehKurpiak

Answer (score 6):

Your autoincrement is probably 10, however this is probably by design. Azure uses ClearDB which uses an autoincrement of 10 with a reason: namely replication.

> When I use auto_increment keys (or sequences) in my database, they
>   increment by 10 with varying offsets. Why?
>
> ClearDB uses circular replication to provide master-master MySQL
>   support. As such, certain things such as auto_increment keys (or
>   sequences) must be configured in order for one master not to use the
>   same key as the other, in all cases. We do this by configuring MySQL
>   to skip certain keys, and by enforcing MySQL to use a specific offset
>   for each key used. The reason why we use a value of 10 instead of 2 is
>   for future development.

You should not change the autoincrement value.

[cleardb faq](https://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq)