# MySQL: Add trailing zero to each row

Tags: mysql

I have a DB setup with two columns, `ID` and `VAL`.

`ID` is an incrementing integer, starting from 1 and increasing by 1 for each row. `VAL` is a simple string.

How can I update each row's `ID` to be 10 times greater? E.g.:
`ID 1, 2, 3` -> `ID 10, 20, 30`

Or is there a better method to adding a trailing zero to the end of every row in a column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Auto increment primary key increases by 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909120/mysql-auto-increment-primary-key-increases-by-10)

Comment: There is no good reason for wanting to do this. None.

Comment: @Strawberry Inserting int vals between 10 and 20 is easier than inserting int vals between 1 and 2. Correct?

Comment: @Filburt No, but thank you. That taught me something new too. I don't need the primary key to increment by 10. I need space padding the existing primary keys to insert values between them.

Comment: That would be an ill-advised use of an auto incrementing primary key.

Comment: agreed with Strawberry; you should not impute any meaning to id values; if you need to order and reorder them, use a separate column for that

Comment: Understood. In that case I should be sorting the table by the `VAL` column and then updating the auto-incrementing primary key to correspond with that order.

Comment: You should not be messing with the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to update the existing values, you simply need to do:

```
update mysterytablename set ID=ID*10 order by ID desc;
```

(The order by is only needed if ID is a primary or unique key, which presumably it is.)

Comment: I can't believe this actually works, so I tested it... and it does. Still seems like a bad idea though .